# Неизвестная ошибка

Tags: html

Вот то, что написал (начало работы).

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Главная</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Просматриваю через браузер и тут это...
[image]

Comment: Какой ещё alt text? О чём идёт речь? У вас тут просто пустая страницу с заголовком окна "Главная". Никакого альттекста быть не может.

Comment: ой... тут просто фотка не вставляется! а как мне её вставить?

Comment: Клик по иконке с картинкой, выбрать файл, нажать ок.

Comment: я фотку уже в начале ставил, но как видите не получается! кажется это я уже проделывал! =(

Comment: нет! не получается... какой-то "alt text" в место фотки!
в общем, у меня тут страничка с заголовком не "Главная" а "Р“Р»Р°РІРЅР°СЏ"

Comment: В общем, в пустой страничке в место "Главная" стоит "Р“Р»Р°РІРЅР°СЏ" и не пойму что мне с ним сделать!

Comment: Добавить картинку попробуйте через другой браузер, например, IE, FF. Изи загрузите на сторонний ресурс, а сюда ссылкой.

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто, попробуй так:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Главная</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```